# How to merge two csr_matrix into one?

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have problems using scipy.sparse.csr_matrix:

for instance:

```
a = csr_matrix([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
b = csr_matrix([[7,8,9],[10,11,12]])
```

how to merge them into

```
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]
```

I know a way is to transfer them into numpy array first:

```
csr_matrix(numpy.vstack((a.toarray(),b.toarray())))
```

but it won't work when the matrix is huge and sparse, because the memory would run out.

so are there any way to merge them together in csr_matrix?

any answers are appreciated!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[scipy.sparse](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/sparse.html) has it's own [stack-methods](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.vstack.html#scipy.sparse.vstack). You can use them directly on your sparse matrices.

```
import scipy.sparse as sp

a = sp.csr_matrix([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
b = sp.csr_matrix([[7,8,9],[10,11,12]])
c = sp.vstack((a,b))  # NOT np.vstack
```

Comment: That works! I should have figured that out ! Thanks a lot !

Comment: The actual work of `sparse.vstack` is done by `sparse.bmat`